# onChange and onBlur not working in redux-form field

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

onChange and onBlur not working in redux-form field. How to fix that

```
class UsersComponent extends PureComponent {
  render() { 
    return (<div>
      <form action="submit" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submitForm)}>
        <Field
          type="text"
          name="mobile"
          hintText="Enter mobile number*"
          component={reduxPhoneNumber}
          validate={required}
          disabled={isSubmitting}
          fullWidth
          autoFocus
          onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
        />
      </form>
    </div>)
  }
}
```

Comment: whats not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `redux-form` reducer to your `combineReducers`:

```
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from 'redux-form';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form: reduxFormReducer,
});
```